# Can't Get DirectShow MPEG-2 Decoder to Output YV12/NV12 Progressive

Tags: h.264, directshow, decoding, samplegrabber

I am attempting to get the MPEG-2 Decoder (aka DTV-DVD Video Decoder) to give me progressive YV12 or NV12 frames that can be uploaded to OpenGL for rendering. But what I'm seeing rendered looks like some form of uncompressed adaptive motion interlacing or else just B or P frames that don't give the full image. (The code that renders the YV12/NV12 in OpenGL works well with other sources, so that's not the problem.)

[image: not how it's supposed to look ;-)]

One important clue: I see one perfectly rendered frame when the movie starts and whenver it loops back to the beginning. This tells me that's the only time I'm getting a full frame of valid YV12/NV12 data.

Shortest description possible:

1) Created a custom Sample Grabber (based on CTransInPlaceFilter) so that I could get samples that have a VIDEOINFOHEADER2. This works as expected, and the sample sizes match expectations for YV12/NV12 at resolution I'm playing. (Helpful example of rolling your own Sample Graabber [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28790/Creating-Custom-DirectShow-SampleGrabber-Filter-fo).)

2) To ensure I only get progressive frames, the CheckInputType() method of my Sample Grabber to return E_FAIL if the dwInterlaceFlags field of the VIDEOINFOHEADER2 has the AMINTERLACE_IsInterlaced flag set.

3) I am setting the eAVDecVideoSoftwareDeinterlaceMode_ProgressiveDeinterlacing flag on the decoder using the ICodecAPI interface with CODECAPI_AVDecVideoSoftwareDeinterlaceMode. (If I don't do this, the decoder won't connect to my Sample Grabber because it doesn't accept interlaced frames.)

4) To debug this, I'm using the IMediaSample2 interface to get the properties of the incoming media samples in the Sample Grabber. The dwTypeSpecificFlags member of the [AM_SAMPLE2_PROPERTIES](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/ms779269(v%3Dvs.85)) struct tells me that the frames are AM_VIDEO_FLAG_INTERLEAVED_FRAME, which I believe indicates I'm getting a full frame instead of a single field. The AM_VIDEO_FLAG_I_SAMPLE bit is also set, for all frames, indicating that I'm getting full "I" frames and not "B" or "P" frames.

5) Given that all frames are "I" frames, I'd expect to see my image instead of gobbledygook as shown above. As mentioned above, the only time I see a valid image when the movie loops back around to the first frame.

6) Last thing: I do see that my samples have the AM_VIDEO_FLAG_WEAVE set. Is this "weaving" of the image the problem?

Thanks,
Mark

Comment: Did you try to run it outside of debugger?

Comment: Good idea, but the result is the same.

Comment: Can you share the video file or give some information about it

Comment: Well, any mp4 file exhibits this behavior. I have a parallel system in built in Windows Media Foundation (need both DS + WMF implemenations for various reasons) and they all play fine under WMF. So I really don't think it's the media.

Comment: Did you compare SampleAttributes/Buffer between MediaFoundation and DirectShow. It's possible that MF does some conversion for you that DirectShow doesn't.